# Getting at rspec shared example name string from within the body, before 'it'?

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to get at the "NAME OF EXAMPLE" passed in to my shared example, as shown in the following code.

```
RSpec.shared_examples "NAME OF EXAMPLE" do |params|
    puts self.name # how to get the shared_examples "NAME OF EXAMPLE" string?
    it "something" do
        true
    end
end
```

What's the equivalent of #{example.full_description} to get at the "NAME OF EXAMPLE" string before the 'it' line? I've been looking at https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example#metadata-instance_method but haven't found the magic incantation (yet). TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "NAME OF EXAMPLE" do |params|
  puts self.description

  it "something" do
    true
  end
end
```

This will include: "behaves like NAME OF EXAMPLE".